# Why doesn't std::set<K, C, A>::erase take a const_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, set

It appears that according to ISO 14882 2003 (aka the Holy Standard of C++) `std::set<K, C, A>::erase` takes `iterator` as a parameter (not a `const_iterator`)

> ***from 23.3.3 [2]***
>
> `void erase(iterator position);`

It might also be noteworthy that on my implementation of STL which came with VS2008, erase takes a `const_iterator` which led to an unpleasant surprise when I tried to compile my code with another compiler. Now, since my version takes a `const_iterator`, then it is possible to implement erase with a `const_iterator`(as if it wasn't self-evident).

I suppose the standards committee had some implementation in mind (or an existing implementation at hand) which would require erase to take an `iterator`.

- If you agree that this is the case, ***can you please describe an implementation of `set::erase` which would require to modify the element that was going to be removed*** (I can't).
- If you disagree, please tell me ***why on Earth would they come up with this decision?*** I mean, erasing an element is just some rearranging of pointers!

It just occurred to me that even in case of iterator you can't modify the element in a set. But the question still holds: why not `const_iterator`, ***especially*** if they're equivalent in some sense?

Comment: You could argue that erasing an element constitutes a change to the element itself (it gets deleted). I think the new C++0x allows erasing of const-iterators. How is this for the other containers?

Comment: @Kerrel: deleted that is its destructor is called. And destructors can be called on const objects (luckily :))

Comment: [set::erase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h4a3515(v=VS.90).aspx) documents an `iterator`, not `const_iterator`.

Comment: GCC 4.6.1 implements `erase(const_iterator)`. 3242 also prescribes const-iterator.

Comment: @Mat: That's very interesting, because I even opened `<set>` and erase takes a `const_iterator` in STL shipped with VS2008 :)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: What's 3242 - the latest draft standard of 0x?

Comment: @Armen: In all likelihood this was just an oversight in the old standard. Like `vector` not having a `data()` member, etc. ... Yes, draft N3242. It's not the latest, though.

Comment: Quick browse through N3242 shows that all `erase()` methods now take const-iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a defect. Since C++11, `set<K,C,A>::erase` takes a `const_iterator`:

```
iterator erase(const_iterator position);
```

[This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2256.html) paper from 2007 illustrated that error and showed implementations to avoid it. I am not sure if this paper is the reason for the change in the standard, but it's probably a good guess.

Comment: he said it's fixed in N3242, but didn't present the paper with description of the issue with the rationale and possible alternatives... did he?

Comment: @armen-tsirunyan: no. I only wanted to give him credit for being faster.

Comment: Yea, apparently it was this paper and option B.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really think of any reason for it to *need* an `iterator`, so I'm leaning toward the arbitrary: any op that modifies the structure would take an `iterator` to let the user know that what previously worked with the `iterator` might not afterward:

- `erase` invalidates the iterator.
- `insert(iter, val)` changes the next value.
- etc.

Comment: Yes, well, that's why erase isn't a const function, because it modifies the `set`. But it doesn't and can't modify `*it`... I didn't understand your point, sorry. What consistency are you talking about? Consistency with what?

Comment: I should not have used that word, sorry.  Tired.  I meant only to say that, while `erase` modifies the `set`, it also modifies the behavior of that specific `iterator`.  It's not too far of a leap to believe someone originally made it an `iterator` to signal that, despite it serving no real purpose.

Comment: Seems a bit far fetched because a `const_iterator` and `iterator` have exactly the same rules of being invalidated. But then, who knows? :)

Answer (score -1):

My only guess is because [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/), [upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/upper_bound/), [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/lower_bound/) and [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/find/) are returning iterator (not const iterator). I don't see other explanation.

Comment: An iterator can be converted to a const_iterator trivially, so I don't think that's an impediment.

Comment: @Mark Well, other explanation could be : a bug in requirements.

Comment: @VJo: "a bug in requirements" could well be an explanation, but your theory about insert, find, etc. just couldn't

Comment: Judging by the paper linked by in the accepted answer, this theory is spot on.  It isn't a reasonable explanation, but who said the standards comittee was reasonable?

Comment: @Mark @Armen It is true that the iterator could be trivially converted into a const_iterator, but it would still require conversion, and the STL was designed to be as optimal as possible (for example, there are no boundary check when using `vector::operator[]`)